# Are extended instruction sets (SSE, MMX) used in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, cpu, assembly

Well, they bring (should bring at least) great increase in performance, isn’t it?

So, I haven’t seen any Linux kernel sources, but ‘d love to ask: are they used somehow? (In this case – there must be some special “code-cap” for system that has no such instructions?)

Comment: So far as I understand, most of those instructions are oriented around matrix mathematics, DSP, graphics encoding/decoding, etc. How much of that do you expect goes on within the kernel?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: you can use SSE instructions to search a bitfield for a non-zero or non-one entry 128b at a time, instead of 32 or 64.  I'm sure there are lots of uses where it would be at least a small speedup in the kernel, except for the fact that saving/restoring the vector regs is expensive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SSE and MMX instruction sets have limited value outside of audio/video and gaming work. You might find a few explicit uses in dark corners of the kernel, but I wouldn't count on it. The answer in the general case is "no, they are not used", nor are they used in most non-kernel/userspace applications.

The kernel does sometimes optionally use certain x86 instructions that are specific to certain CPUs (e.g. present on some AMD or Intel models but not all, nor vice-versa), such as `syscall`, but these are different from the SIMD instruction sets you're referring to, and are not part of some wider set of similarly-themed extensions.

After Mark's answer, I went looking. The only place I could easily identify them being used is in [the RAID 6 library](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=tree;f=lib/raid6) (which also has support for AltiVec, which is the PowerPC SIMD instruction set).

(Be wary just grepping the tree, there are a lot of spots where the kernel "knows" about SSE/MMX to support user-space applications, but isn't actually using it. Also a couple cases of unfortunate variable names that have absolutely nothing to do with SSE, e.g. in the SCTP implementation.)

Comment: But that's only the places in the kernel where SIMD instructions are explicitly used. If I compile the kernel myself, is there any reason why I shouldn't use the `-ftree-vectorize` and `-msse*` options to tell gcc to use SIMD where it sees fit?

Comment: @us2012 That's probably a very bad idea if for no other reason than that the kernel isn't designed for it, and you may unexpectedly clobber user-space SIMD register values (or user-space may clobber values left there by the kernel code). Messing with kernel compile flags is just generally a bad idea, it tends to break things, either by turning up obscure GCC bugs, or breaking low-level assumptions. Unless you're doing research, compile flag choices are best left to the kernel devs. You don't want to play with them just trying to squeeze more performance out of your system.

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot about the registers. That makes sense.

Comment: @us2012 Here's a proposal to use it for [memcpy] (http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OTgwMQ).  In general, this would only be appropriate for copying large amounts of data, but can produce a performance increase in those cases. On a related note, nVidia has sponsored research for doing (in-kernel) encryption on their GPU that's shown some promising results, but is completely proprietary and will never make it into the mainline in its current form.  Still, it has demonstrated the possibilities.

Answer (score 5):

There are severe restrictions on using vector registers and floating point registers in kernel code. See e.g. chapter 6.3 of "Calling conventions for different C++ compilers and operating systems". http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals

Answer (score 3):

They are used in the kernel for a few things, such as

- Software RAID
- Encryption (possibly)

However, I believe it always checks their presence first.

Answer (score 0):

"cpu simd instructions use FPU"

erm, no, not as I understand it. They're in part a modern and (much) more efficient replacement for FPU instructions, but a large part of the SIMD instruction set deals with integer operations.
I've never looked very hard at it, but I suppose (ok, hope) that SIMD code generated by a recent gcc version will not clobber any registers or state.

Comment: Kernel devs describe it this way because Linux saves/restores vector and FPU register state together.  The vector regs are just lumped in with the FPU regs.  SSE code *will* clobber some of the SSE registers (xmm0-xmm15).  That's unavoidable.